# Computed property doesn’t work as expected

Tags: ember.js

I stuck on the next problem. I have a component with a "chosen" input where user can select multiple options. I want to map list of selected ids to list of another ids and send them to parent controller. How it looks now:

**components/filter-menu.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  selectedFakeIngredients: [],

  selectedRealIngredients: Ember.computed('selectedFakeIngredients', function(key, value) {
    var self = this;
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      return value;
    }
    return this.get('selectedFakeIngredients').map(function(item) {
      return self.get('filteredIngredients')[item].groupId;
    });
  }),

  actions: {
      doSearch() {
        this.sendAction("doSearch");
      }
  }
});
```

**templates/components/filters-menu.hbs**

```
{{ember-chosen multiple=true searchContains=true displaySelectedOptions=false content=filteredIngredients optionValuePath="id" optionLabelPath="caption" value=selectedFakeIngredients action="doSearch" placeholder="Напишите ингредиент..."}}
```

**templates/builder.hbs**

```
{{filters-menu clearFilters="clearFilters" doSearch="doSearch" toggleType="toggleType" toggleOption="toggleOption" selectedRealIngredients=selectedIngredients ingredients=ingredients}}
```

When I just set directly "selectedFakeIngredients" in builder.hbs all works fine (expect these are incorrect ids). But if set computed property "selectedRealIngredients" it is not working at all. "selectedRealIngredients" function not called. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to achieve needed behaviour?

P.S. I'm using latest stable version of EmberJS.

Comment: The way you have defined `selectedRealIngredients` it will change only when `selectedFakeIngredients` itself has changed. Try to list the following dependencies: `'selectedFakeIngredients.[]', 'filteredIngredients.[].groupId'`.

Comment: Another problem: defining arrays and objects (`selectedFakeIngredients`) directly as a property will make it shared between instances of that prototype. This means all `filter-menu` will share it. The solution is to set them on init.

Comment: A nitpick: you can use the new [get/set computed property syntax](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html#toc_new-computed-syntax).

Comment: 'selectedFakeIngredients.[]' - it helps me. Thanks. @locks I will look on the new syntax, thank you.